# Why is WebView blocking my ExpandableListView's expansion?

Tags: android, webview, expandablelistview

I've been working with ExpandableListViews before and I know about checkBoxes, Buttons, etc.

It is essential to setFocusable to **false** for any of these widgets that could be found on the XML that will serve as a groupView of our list, othervise, clicking on the group cell will not expand the group, since these widgets will steal focus from it.

BUT, If I put WebView in my GroupView, and **setFocusable & setFocusableInTouchMode to false**, I will still **NOT** be able to expand the group.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="91dp"
android:background="#ffffff">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="91dp"
    android:id="@+id/sth_cell_img_correct"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_checked" />

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:id="@+id/webView2" />


</LinearLayout>
```

But, if I remove WebView from the XML, I can expand / shrink cells with no trouble whatsoever.

There must be some other thing I should do here.
Som other attribute should be set to false, or something like that, but I cannot figure out what exactly.

Does anyone has a clue ?

Comment: try search some info about autoresize for webview, there are a lots of it on SO

Comment: What does autoresize have to do anything with this issue ?